# Increasing the cluster size in Google Container Engine

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

How do I add VM instances to my existing Container Engine cluster?

I understand that I can add pods via replication controllers, but it seems there can be multiple pods per VM instance. Adding 50 new pods to my initial 3 VM cluster just distributed those pods evenly and did not start new instances. Not really helpful if I want to scale my app due to increased load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, there isn't a way to scale your cluster. We are working on integrating Container Engine with the recently announced Managed Instance Groups and Cloud AutoScaling Service.

Stay tuned!

Comment: Is this still accurate?

Answer (score 1):

Resizing a cluster is now possible, see the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/resize-cluster)

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/resize-cluster

$ gcloud container clusters describe CLUSTER_NAME --format yaml | grep -A 1 instanceGroupUrls

$ gcloud compute instance-groups managed resize gke-example-b937f2ba-group --zone us-central1-f --size 4