# Google Container Engine Roadmap

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm very interesting in the new Google Cloud Service: Google Container Engine, namely in be a able to write systems that can scale using containers' properties.

I saw the StackOverflow questions:

- [Autoscaling in Google Container Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899789/autoscaling-in-google-container-engine)
- [Increasing the cluster size in Google Container Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899733/increasing-the-cluster-size-in-google-container-engine)

And I understood that the auto-scale (and other features) are planned, however, I didn't see any release dates.

When are the referred auto-scale features/integrations be released/available?

When will the Google Container Engine reach Beta (leave Alpha)?

Does Google Container Engine have a roadmap with release dates that can be consulted?

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes roadmap is here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/roadmap.md

Unfortunately, Google Container Engine hasn't released a roadmap yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know the planned month/year to Google Container Engine reach Beta?

Comment: Google container engine now has been release for everyone https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that you can now do both Autoscaling and Resize a running Google Container Engine Cluster by using Instance Groups - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/